# How to add button or checkbox to google map .?

Tags: android, google-maps, button, checkbox

I want to add button to my google map activity but I am getting an error at run-time.

I want to select a location on the map with a long press, with a confirmation that the location was intended to be selected.

I press the checkbox and send the location info to another activity, but I am getting an error on creating a checkbox at run-time.  The text views are created, but the checkboxes and buttons are not created at run-time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<fragment
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/haritafragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtViewAddress"/>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
    android:id="@+id/cbGetAdress"
    android:checked="false" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Does anyone see a problem with this code that might fix this?**

Comment: Post your logcat with the error